# Angular & Firebase Authentication: Facebook login secure connection problem

Tags: angular, firebase, facebook, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase Authentication on an Angular web application. Everything works as a web application including Facebook authentication using the following codes:

```
 AuthLogin(provider: any) {
    return this.afAuth
      .signInWithPopup(provider)
      // .signInWithRedirect(provider) <-- Also tried this. Working as web but not if compiled to Android App
      .then(() => {
        this.authUser = this.auth.currentUser
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }
```

I decided to publish it as a mobile application using Capacitor and everything looks great except that when I install it on an Android device and then try logging in, the following error occurs:

[image]

> Facebook detected app isn't using secure connection to transfer
> information.

Do I need to have a separate code base for my mobile app to remedy this or am I just missing a step?